# Finding the actual size of an object using kinect depth data

Tags: opencv, kinect

I was wondering how would I figure out the actual size of the object, using the kinect depth values.

For example, if the kinect sees a round object in front of it, and the round object take 100 pixels of space in the image, and the depth value the kinect gives is x, how would I know the actual size of the round object?

I don't need it in units like meters or anything, I am just trying to find a formula to calculate the size of object that is independant from how far the object is from the kinect.

I am using OpenCV and the kinect SDK, if anything is useful there please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the size in 3d, given a size in 2d, you just do:

```
3d_rad = 2d_rad * depth
```

So if the ball appears on the screen as 10 pixels wide and is 1 metre away, it really is 10 "units" wide. Do a little playing to find out the units returned, I'm unsure what they will be.

Suppose you have a 20 pixel radius ball on screen and the depth is returned as 30, the real size of the ball is 20*30 = 600 units. Again, I'm unsure what unit exactly, it depends on the camera, but it is a constant so play around with it. Put a 1 metre ball in front of the camera, far enough away that it looks like 100 pixels. The reciprocal of that distance should be the conversion factor to turn the units you have into centimetres and can be used as a constant. For example:

```
3d_rad_in_cm = conversion * 2d_rad * depth
```